# Evil proxy for testing client/server interaction

Tags: macos, testing, networking, client-server

I'm writing a client that talks to a remote server over HTTP. I would like to place an evil proxy between the client and the server that would (randomly?) affect the traffic on the wire.

Some things that I would like to happen:

- arbitrary delays for the response
- arbitrary HTTP errors
- this scenario is hard to imagine with TCP but what the hell: truncated responses (ie malformed data)
- temporary unavailability (though that seems hard given that this would have to be done at the lower network level).
- predefined custom errors (eg: every request comes back with a service error)

Basically I want to simulate a range of networking conditions that the users of this software are going to experience out in the real world and make sure the client handles them gracefully.

I suspect (hope) that something like that already exists. Please point me in the right direction!

Thanks

Comment: IIRC some companies built similar modules for internal testing... I do not know of any free or commercial proxy allowing for that much control... basically you would start with an existing opensource proxy and modify/extend it for your needs...

Comment: Yeah, I found [Mallory](http://intrepidusgroup.com/insight/mallory/). It supports plugins but I want to see if there's something out there already, before I invest time into learning Python.

Comment: I think the better choice is to mock network interaction classes, so you could easily describe such scenarios in the test case code, otherwise it would be quite difficult to manage such system.

Comment: Yeah you're right that would be the preferable way. Unfortunately the network code wasn't architected in a way that would facilitate testing. I believe it's quite solid anyway but a real life test would be better than no testing.

Comment: Writing a proxy like that is straightforward in a scripting language like perl or python - as Yahia says it's commonly done internally for testing.

Comment: Why would I want to reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[HTTP Test Tool (htt)](http://htt.sourceforge.net) seems like what you need here. It has [the ability to operate as a proxy and a reverse-proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Test_Tool#Proxy_Development) for testing those cases specifically, when a mock framework is insufficient to the task.

For a *truly* evil proxy, consider using [Squid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squid_%28software%29) in conjunction with the [Metasploit Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasploit_Project) and some of the tools in [BackTrack Linux](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/). That seems to be a bit beyond your project scope, though!

([Additional tools to consider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_testing_tools), plus [one more](http://webinject.org/))

Answer (score 3):

Fiddler[1](http://www.fiddler2.com/) is a scriptable traffic viewer/proxy.

Answer (score 3):

You could try [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) - everything you wrote can be simulated using that tool. It's also great for debugging communication issues between your application and the server. Saved me a lot of work when I was implementing XML-RPC.

There are some great extensions that can help you and you can even [write your own](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/dev/IFiddlerExtension.asp) if you need something really special.

[EDIT]
Since this is mac question, you can try [webscarab](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_WebScarab_Project) or [charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) (the second one is paid). But you can still run the proxy on any machine - even virtual. So if you have spare win license...

Comment: @EightyEight as I doubt that fiddler will run on mono, I've edited my answer and added links to tools that will run on mac.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're on a Mac, you have `ipfw` built in to your system.  From a terminal, `man ipfw` for information.

`ipfw` manages firewall rules, including a set of rules called "Dummynet" which can be used to introduce packet loss and latency.  This doesn't address ALL your concerns, but it allows you to affect your traffic at the network level without involving an extra piece of software.

I found [an article on WaterRoof](http://osxdaily.com/2010/08/04/ipfw-gui-front-end-for-mac-os-x-waterroof/) which appears to be a GUI `ipfw` rule editor that supports Dummynet.  There are probably others.

Also have a look at [this AFP548 article](http://www.afp548.com/article.php?story=20060214081244545) on traffic shaping with Dummynet.  If you're fairly comfy at a command line, you should be good to go.

Note that Dummynet does NOT provide tools for all the things you listed in your question; it only lets you simulate a number of network problems like latency and packet loss.  For anything involving alteration of data at the HTTP level, I agree with others that [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is probably the tool to use.

Also learn about Chrome/Chromium's "Inspect Element" tool.  (Right-click, then select it from the bottom of most context menus.)  It provides a detailed look at HTTP client and server headers, along with the ability to modify hidden form variables, record entire sessions for later viewing, etc.  Very handy stuff.